# Xamarin Android Menu - NavigationView background image and fullscreen

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, navigationview, android-navigationview

I need help with Menu in Android...

- First: I need in menu image in background
- Second: if it possible will    be good full screen menu

**My menu layout looks like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/nav_background"
      android:src="@drawable/test_back"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:alpha="1"
      android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView 
                                              android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
                                              android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                              android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                              android:layout_gravity="end"
                                              android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
                                              android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                              local:itemTextColor="@color/white"
                                              android:background="@color/main_red_opacity"
                                             >

  <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                 android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout  
      android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                   android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/nav_menuItem"
        android:text="MenuItem"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
      />
      <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/nav_menuItem"
        android:text="MenuItem"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
      />
      <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/main_gray"
        />
      <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/nav_menuItem"
        android:text="MenuItem"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
      />
      <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/nav_menuItem"
        android:text="MenuItem"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
      />
      <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/nav_menuItem"
        android:text="MenuItem"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
      />

      </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:src="@drawable/logo"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:id="@+id/logoBottom"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This works but I need layout with Menu Items on bottom of menu but result is:
[image]

and without ImageView it looks like this:
[image]

This I need but with image in background...

**EDIT**

```
  <!-- Navigation style -->
  <style name="NavigationViewStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <!-- menu item text size-->
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">60dp</item>
    <!-- menu item height-->
  </style>
```

**Github demo:** https://github.com/pinkysek/XabluDemoApp/tree/master/XabluAppTest

Comment: Please remove the `ImageView` which id is `nav_background`, and add background to your `RelativeLayout`, Please show the ` android:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"`, I don't know what is your problem, I just try your code, and there are some errors in your layout. I suggest you edit your question.

Comment: @JoeLv ok edited and added NavigationViewStyle

Comment: Do you want to the `ImageView` which id is `nav_background` to full screen?

Comment: if is possible I want whole menu to full screen so ye ImageView too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `RelativeLayout` to `FrameLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">
  <FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
   android:background="@drawable/test_back"
    >
  </FrameLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and add `android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"` in your `FrameLayout` which id is `navigation_frame` in `activity_main.axml` layout, like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigation_frame"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start" />
```

Comment: still same problem + image background is deformed...when is there ImageView and centerCrop image is ok..

Comment: Are you using `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: Could you please give me a demo which can reproduce your problem? Thanks!!!

Comment: Change `RelativeLayout` to `FrameLayout`, you can try it.

Comment: nice it works well.... but still is possible make NavigationView 100% width of screen? and not like 80%?

Comment: Ok, I will test it  and  I will leave you a message later.

Comment: It works when I did this   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigation_frame"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-65dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-65dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start" />